# can't save values from loop R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have created a loop taking all values from character A:

```
[1] "Arsenal"        "Aston Villa"    "Cardiff City"   "Chelsea"        "Crystal Palace"
[6] "Everton"  
...
```

and running through data frame `england` and finding all corresponding values of other variable.

```
for (i in 1:length(teams)) { print(sum(england$hgoal[england$home == teams[i]]))
```

I have this result

```
[1] 36
[1] 22
[1] 20
...
```

but for some reason I can't save this result. I want to store it in data frame `home_goals` so I tried to add this loop to

```
home_goals$goals <- ...
```

also tried to save it as list, vector but it either gives back NULL or just save only the first value..

I hope i was clear enough.

Comment: you should try to give a minimal workable example of what you are trying to do. It is difficult to understand what you are after otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to be as clear as I can without spamming with too much info. Anyway, what you've done is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could help.

Create a data.frame with 'goals` as a variable

```
home_goals <- data.frame(goals = numeric(length(teams)))

for (i in 1:length(teams)) { 
  home_goals$goals[i] <- sum(england$hgoal[england$home == teams[i]])
}
```